# Is EPIC (Perl plugin) for Eclipse still being actively developed?

Tags: eclipse, perl

According to [EPIC's profile on the Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/epic-eclipse-perl-integration#.UEZUMY1lQmU), the latest version is 0.5 and it was last updated on July 8, 2010.

If it isn't actively developed anymore, what are other popular alternatives on Eclipse?

Comment: I use it a lot, and I believe it was updated in the test branch about a half your ago, but then again who am I to trust my memory...

Comment: I also use it.  Despite not being actively developed, EPIC still seems to work fine for the purposes one expects (syntax highlighting, pointing out lines with syntax errors, folding, search-and-replace, integration with repository plugins). It will even occasionally provide auto-complete suggestions for variables in scope and methods; I treat these as beneficent voodoo, since I don't expect that for a dynamic language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is EPIC (Perl plugin) for Eclipse still being actively developed?

There are some stats available on the [sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/):

- Last commit: April '12 (!= release)
- Until now, there have been 1245 repository commits, of which 72 occured since 2010-01-01.
- There are open, high-priority bugs dating back to 2006
- There are currently 212 open bugs, 165 of which are unassigned to a developer
- There are very recent bugs (2012-08-31) of which some are assigned to a developer

So the answer seems to be *"No, it is not being actively developed, but there is a lone developer standing his ground and hunting bugs"*.

> alternatives

</rational-and-abjective>

It is my (personal and very disputable) belief that an IDE is of limited use when writing Perl, due to the dynamic and interpreted nature of this language: You have no source to compile, so automatic make-file generation is a non-issue, and many editors support some degree of code completition. Any combination of Editor + Terminal + Documentation will do fine.

The "big names" of Perl IDEs are EPIC, Komodo, and Padre of course, followed by Emacs and any *nix OS.

Answer (score 1):

The last update on the [Sourceforge page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/e-p-i-c/) is v0.6.35 on 15-Sep-2011

I take that back. The latest version appears to be v0.6.35, but the *last update* is variously stated as 21-May-2009 (in the name of the download file) 15-Sep-2011 (stated as 'Last Update' on the Sourceforge page) and the last feature request to be fulifilled and closed was on 25-Mar-2012 (according the the patches tracker)